# Big red cross on varied controls

Tags: .net, winforms, paint

So we have an application that is quite large in size and takes up an average of 75,000kb of memory when it runs (this goes up and back down when opening other windows but not by much).

Recently, we have had a few calls into our support team about the Red Cross Of Doom as it is affectionately called.

This appears on controls that are standard WinForms controls with no customization whatsoever (they are also not placed in any custom containers).

After some research, we found that it seems to only trigger if an exception has occurred in a paint event assigned to that control. However, these controls have no events for painting which means that it must be underlying.

Our thought process is that this may be happening on systems with very low memory but that is a bit of a stab in the dark. Backing up this theory is the fact that this issue is intermittent.

**BIG RED CROSS OF DOOM on a datagridview**

[image: Big Red Cross Of Doom DGV]

**BIG RED CROSS OF DOOM everywhere**

[image: Big Red Cross Of Doom Everywhere]

The question is simply to either confirm our suspicions about the memory issue, or give us another reason, and hopefully a way to get round it.

NOTE :-
I know WinForms is a little old now and not really supported but this application is very big and therefore suggestions on converting to WPF or anything else will not be possible.

Comment: There's usually an exception when this happens... have you tried setting a global exception handler to see if this is your case?

Comment: Unfortunately we cannot actually replicate this as our machines have an abundant amount of memory. We have put a line of code to write to a hidden text file the exception text when triggered, however, this cannot be distributed to our client for the next few days.

Comment: Is this a static defect? I mean - does it happens "by itself" or can you trace it to some user action (window re-sizing)? Do these clients ever get a correct rendering?

Comment: Yes they do get correct rendering, as mentioned this is an intermittent issue and happens what seems to be random (which i know can never be the case) but no, we cannot trace this back to a user action so far.

Comment: None of these controls are using OwnerDraw?

Comment: We can't answer this without seeing your code.  Bad paint code or updating data bound controls in a background thread are usually the culprit.

Comment: No, these are not owner drawn in the slightest, no internal overriding calls and no external paint events. Therefore also seeing the code is not possible because it is not there, there are also no threads on these forms so that is out of the window as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem sometimes and it had caused for problems in the TOOLBOX of Visual Studio - some references were wrong.

I succesfully solved this using the following procedures:

```
1) Delete the project´s OBJ folder.
2) Delete the .SUO file.
3) Press BUILD - CLEAN
4) Press BUILD - BUILD SOLUTION (not rebuild)
```

if these WON´T solve, continue with:

```
5) Delete the CONTROL in the Toolbox (one by one is easier);
6) Right-click in Toolbox and CHOOSE ITEMS in the same tab;
7) Locate the control/reference of this control in the window will appear (.NET Framework components for the default ones and BROWSE for any custom one)  and check it again.
8) If the control had disapeared from form, you need to put it again there.
9) Recompile again (BUILD - BUILD SOLUTION).
```

Good luck.

Comment: Sorry, but as mentioned, this is only an issue that occurs on a customers machine. Therefore we cannot replicate it here and doing builds, rebuilds and toolbox references will have no affect since it already works for us.

Comment: SO, considering your comments and the others suggestion and also, considering the NET Framework is OK at users machines, you have really a problem related to MEMORY, specifically, WINDOWS RESOURCES memory area (always too much lower than RAM).

Comment: OK, that was the track we were heading down and just wanted confirmation. We are looking into making a environment to replicate this so may post an answer in the near future. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You´re welcome and I´m sad of not solved your problem as wished... Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

This happened to me often when using 3rd Party software and trying to display the form without the software's display dependencies - Did not affect the actual execution.

The software was SAP Crystal Reporting I think...

Comment: This is an application that we are developing so not third party, we have checked the software's display dependencies and nothing looks out of the ordinary.

Comment: hmmmm, I'm not too sure then. Good luck.